# Join three tables for different Count

Tags: sql, join, count

I have 3 tables.

Team

```
   TeamId        Team 
    1       Manchester United
    2       Arsenal 
    3       Liverpool
```

Match

```
 MatchId HomeTeamId AwayTeamId  MatchStartDate Match_WonBy
  3         1           2          2/2/2015       2
  8         3           1          6/2/2015       3
```

Score

```
  ScoreId MatchId TeamId      ScorTime
  1         3      1      2/2/2015 12:30:00
  2         3      2      2/2/2015 12:35:00
  3         3      1      2/2/2015 12:38:00
  4         8      1      6/2/2015 12:45:00
  5         8      1      6/2/2015 12:49:00
```

Ive tried this but I fail to get it.

```
SELECT Team.TeamName, COUNT(h.HomeTeamId) AS TotalMatch,
    SUM(CASE WHEN h.Match_Status = Team.TeamId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HomeScore,
    SUM(CASE WHEN h.Match_WonBy  = Team.TeamId OR a.Match_Status= Team.TeamId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total
FROM Team RIGHT JOIN Match h
ON Team.TeamId = h.HomeTeamId JOIN Match a
ON Team.TeamId = a.AwayTeamId  
GROUP BY Team.TeamName
```

I needed this which I am not getting.[image]

FYI: its not a homework.

Here the points are calculated by multiplying 3 to the win and adding 1 to the draw.

Comment: How you know its a `draw`(what is the value for `column Match_WonBy`

Comment: There is no `TeamName` column according to the schema you gave us.  Also, you should label the question with the type of SQL you are using.

Comment: @Praveen : for draw the value is 0.. so its a draw.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen :TeamName is Team.. Just copied  pasted the query form my sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
    t.Team,
    count(x.TeamId) played,
    sum(coalesce(x.win, 0)) as win,
    sum(coalesce(x.loss, 0)) as loss,
    count(x.TeamId) - sum(coalesce(x.win, 0)) - sum(coalesce(x.loss, 0)) as draw, 
    sum(coalesce(x.win, 0)) * 3 + (count(x.TeamId) - sum(coalesce(x.win, 0)) - sum(coalesce(x.loss, 0))) as point
from Team t
left join (
    select 
    HomeTeamId TeamId,
    case when Match_WonBy = HomeTeamId then 1 else 0 end win,
    case when Match_WonBy = AwayTeamId then 1 else 0 end loss
    from Match
    union all
    select
    AwayTeamId TeamId,
    case when Match_WonBy = AwayTeamId then 1 else 0 end win,
    case when Match_WonBy = HomeTeamId then 1 else 0 end loss
    from Match
) x on t.TeamId = x.TeamId
group by t.Team
order by
sum(coalesce(x.win, 0)) * 3 + (count(x.TeamId) - sum(coalesce(x.win, 0)) - sum(coalesce(x.loss, 0))) desc
```

Comment: borther thank you so much. Relly appreciate your help.